# Implemented Custom Binary search for 4 arguments but how to avoid the iteration to get lowerbound?

Tags: java, comparator, binary-search

I am trying to implement custom binary search. I am clear on how to pass arguments and what to compare to get in which kind of sorted order but I want to avoid the iteration as I want to get lower bound.

I am trying to get the highest rating "os" with the desired "query" using binary search. Am I implementing the binary search wrong here?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CustomBinarySearch {
    static class OsDetails{
        String os;
        int memory, version, price, rating;
        OsDetails(String s1, int a1, int b1, int c1, int d1){
            os = s1;
            memory = a1;
            version = b1;
            price = c1;
            rating = d1;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return os+"-"+String.valueOf(memory)+"-"+String.valueOf(version)+"-"+String.valueOf(price)+"-"+String.valueOf(rating);
        }
    } // custom class for os details 
    static class Comp implements Comparator<OsDetails>{
        public int compare(OsDetails p1, OsDetails p2) {
            if(p1.os.equals(p2.os) && p1.memory==p2.memory && p1.version==p2.version) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    } // binary search comparator
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        ArrayList<OsDetails> list = new ArrayList<OsDetails>();
        StringTokenizer st;
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            list.add(new OsDetails(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), 
                    Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())));
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<OsDetails>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(OsDetails p1, OsDetails p2) {
                if(p1.os.equals(p2.os)) {
                    if(p1.memory==p2.memory) {
                        if(p1.version==p2.version) {
                            if(p1.rating==p2.rating) {
                                return p1.price-p2.price;
                            }
                            else {
                                return p2.rating-p1.rating;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            return p1.version-p2.version;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return p1.memory-p2.memory;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return p1.os.compareTo(p2.os);
                }
            }
        }); // sorting on the based on 1. String 2. memory(2 or 4) 3. version (32 or 64 bit) 4. rating(higher to lower) 5. price(low to high)
        System.out.println(list);
        int q = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int i = 0;i<q;i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            OsDetails pfind = new OsDetails(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), 0);
            int j = Collections.binarySearch(list, pfind, new Comp());
            int k=j;
            if(j<0) {
                System.out.println(-1);
                continue;
            }
            OsDetails plist = list.get(j);
            while(k>=0) {
                plist = list.get(k);
                if(pfind.os.equals(plist.os) && pfind.memory==plist.memory && pfind.version==plist.version && pfind.price>=plist.price) {
                    k--;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            } // I want to avoid this iteration please suggest some way out of this
            plist = list.get(k+1);
            if(pfind.os.equals(plist.os) && pfind.memory==plist.memory && pfind.version==plist.version && pfind.price>=plist.price)
                System.out.println(plist.rating);
            else
                System.out.println(-1);
        }
    }
}
/*
7
android 2 32 76 84
ios 2 32 78 100
windows 2 32 56 79
windows 2 32 110 100
windows 2 64 73 38
ios 4 64 100 500
ios 4 64 107 50
3
ios 4 64 300
windows 2 32 500
ios 2 32 70
*/
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Beyond that: your code is really hard to read. It starts with the (sorry) lousy variable naming. s, a, b, c, d ... these names mean all nothing.

Comment: Indeed ... `Pair` is a strange name for a tuple of 5.

Comment: And just for the record: please dont forget about accepting an answer at some point.

Comment: Sorry for the lousy code, I am used to small syntax due to time constraint, let me edit the code and apply changes mentioned by you @GhostCat

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First of all, your first comparator only returns 0 or -1. But the comparator interface says: -1, 0, **or** 1. So your implementation there **must** be wrong somehow.

Then: one of the reasons why your code is so hard to read: naming variables a, b, c, d, to then write *manual* code to "deal" with those 4 values is "wrong" conceptually.

Those 4 values should go into a **list** or **array**. And then your Pair class could be named `FixedLengthArray` or something alike. And then you could avoid such endless cascades of if/else ... by iterating these arrays when needing to make comparisons.

Your real problem isn't iteration, it is the way how you represent your data here.

Comment: Can you explain how returning +1 or -1 affects the binary search, like in which direction does the binary search move, right of the mid value or left of the mid value. In my understanding the binary search method returns 0 if the searching conditions are matched else returns -1.

Comment: Glad to hear that!